# How to combine observables but emit a value for each as it occurs

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I would like to get each emitted value from the combined observable. I do not need the final value for all which is achieved by operators like combineLatest, forkJoin etc.

I am looking for an operator that will make the below code shorter but keep the same behaivor.

```
this.keyPress$.pipe(debounceTime(1000))
.subscribe(
  (d) => {
    console.log('keypress');
    resetInterval();
  }
);

this.mouseMove$.pipe(debounceTime(1000))
.subscribe(
  (d) => {
    console.log('mouseMove');
  }
);


this.click$.pipe(debounceTime(1000))
.subscribe(
  (d) => {
    console.log('click');
  }
);
```

Is there a way or an operator I can use to achieve this?

Comment: combineLatest wont give u the final emitted value. I think combineLatest will fit here

Comment: combineLatest only emits if all the emissions were triggered, meaning that a click, mousemove, keypress all have to be emitted before combineLatest can emit a value

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem right, you may try something along these lines

```
k$ = this.keyPress$.pipe(
  debounceTime(1000),
  tasp(() => {
    console.log('keypress');
    resetInterval();
  })

m$ = this.mouseMove$.pipe(
  debounceTime(1000),
  tap(() => console.log('mouseMove'))
  );


c$ = this.click$.pipe(
  debounceTime(1000),
  tap(() => console.log('click'))
  )


merge(k$, m$, c$).subscribe()
```

It does not reduces your code, probably, but requires just one explicit subscription, which may be an advantage in itself since, if for instance you need to unsubscribe at some point, you have only one subscription to deal with.

Comment: Yeah thanks, I can use the approach if there is no way to reduce the code. I like the fact that I will only unsubscribe once with the `merge`